# Is there a term for when lyrics are integrated with words from a sampled beat?

Tags: terminology, lyrics, samples, rap

Is there a term for when the lyrics of a song are integrated with words from a sampled beat? I see this particularly in hip-hop. For example, the hook from Game's "Dreams" has lyrics:

Lettin' the ink from my pen bleed / Cause Martin Luther King had a ("Dream") / Aaliyah had a ("Dream"), Left Eye had a ("Dream") / So I reached out to Kanye and ("I brought you all my dreams")

where the words in parentheses are from the beat, which is sampled from a Jerry Butler song.

Is there a specific term for this kind of integration of lyrics and samples?

Comment: While I can't definitely say no—it's hard to prove a negative—I very much doubt it. I know what you mean but I've never heard a term for it. And in my experience working with rappers, or anybody really, people tend to develop their own vocabularies localized to the people they work with (ex. "That snare is too blue"). It's only once something becomes massively popular and over a period of time that it starts to get standardized vocab. More commonly you might hear somebody reference other recordings to explain the concept (ex. "That sample thing that {artist} did on the hook to {song}".

Comment: It's still simply a form of sampling - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(music) - so, the term itself is "sampling"...

Comment: we just call it "primo style", as DJ Premier was king of that vibe

Answer (score 0):

The only term I've ever seen is "Vocal samples" or "sampling the vocals."  Lyrics are always integrated with the samples, vocal or instrumental, in hiphop.